# XSL issues with XML elements having a COLON

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I'm running an XSLT against a 3rd party XML file that has element names that contain colons.

```
<xccdf:TestResult xmlns:xccdf="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2"
  <xccdf:benchmark href="ine" id="abs"/><xccdf:title xml:lang="en-US">TestConten</xccdf:title>
....
....
```

Now in my XSL file, when i try to extract the value of an atribute or the data under an element

```
<xsl:value-of select="xccdf:TestResult/xccdf:benchmark/@id"/>
<xsl:value-of select="xccdf:TestResult/xccdf:title"/>
```

I get no value.  I get empty data.

In the XSLT, i declared the namespace too.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xccdf="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2">
```

Am not sure how to extract the value of the element or attribute!!
Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you include COMPLETE XML and XSLT files? They may be small but they should be complete.

Comment: H Marcus,  Here is the XML file
http://wikisend.com/download/839932/xccdf-results.xml

And this is the XSL
http://wikisend.com/download/931526/xccdf 2.xsl

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow should be self-contained. Any hyperlink to the outside world might break at any time. Is it possible to shorten your files appropriately and integrate them into your question?

Comment: hmmm well, in the question, i did include the section of XML that has 2 elements <xccdf:benchmark> & <xccdf:title> 

Now we are trying to access the value of an atribute 'id' under <xccdf:benchmark> element or the data under an element 'xccdf:title' element.

No as these elements have the ':' character in them, XSL is not able to get the values.

Its a huge XML files and XSL file, i hope u got the gist of my question?

Comment: I would like to reproduce your problem to help you. There are two issues: a) your XML is malformed. I cannot use it as input and b) your XSLT code lacks the context which is very important for correctness of the XPath expression that you are using.

Comment: In your *linked* stylesheet, you declare the namespace as `xmlns:xccdfSchema="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1"`, so your XPath expressions *in the stylesheet* should actually be prefixed by `xccdfSchema` and not `xccdf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your linked stylesheet, you declare the namespace as xmlns:xccdfSchema="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1", so your XPath expressions in the stylesheet should actually be prefixed by xccdfSchema and not xccdf. –  helderdarocha May 30 at 13:22

The suggestion made by @helderdarocha worked.

All i needed to do was the set the namespace and use xccdfSchema:ElementName in the XPath expressions